# GWT:how to get the value of a checkbox of a cellTable

Tags: gwt

[image]

I have this situation , i want to delete the  objects in this celltable whose checkbox is Check on the clik of this "Delete" Button ,

Any idea how to get those objects whose checkbox is checked in this cellTable, when i click the delte button ..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your requirement with delete single row, then You can use SingleSelectionModel otherwise MulitiSelectionModel in celltable. I have written some code with single selection model,It may give some idea. i.e.

```
selectionModel = new SingleSelectionModel<T>();
cellTable.setSelectionModel(selectionModel) //Set into your cellTable:
```

When you select a checkbox, then row will auto selected and object will set in to selection model.

```
  CheckboxCell checkboxCell=new CheckboxCell(true, false); 
            Column<T, Boolean> boolColumn=new Column<T, Boolean>(
                        checkboxCell) {
            @Override
            public Boolean getValue(T object) {                            
             return selectionModel.isSelected(object); 
        }
        };
```

On delete button click,use selected object,It will provide you a object for delete.
   `selectionModel.getSelectedObject();`

Answer (score 1):

@junaidp, As you haven't provided any code, I'm assuming that you have used CheckBoxCell to generate checkbox column and assigned MultiSelectionModel to your cellTable. You can use the following code:

```
Set<T> selectedObjects = ((MultiSelectionModel<T>)(cellTable.getSelectionModel())).getSelectedSet();
```

Here **selectedObjects** will be of type T, that you should have specified as `CellTable<T>`.
**selectedObjects** will be objects, associated to checked rows only.

Answer (score 1):

You can check for a given cell's selected status with:

```
Column<CellInfo, Boolean> checkColumn =
      new Column<MemberInfo, Boolean>(new CheckboxCell(true, false)) {
        public Boolean getValue(CellInfo object) {
          // Get the value from the selection model.
          return selectionModel.isSelected(object);
        }
      };
```